# Android Studio: How to solve "Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable' " in API 17?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to retrieve `JSON` values from Thingspeak to send to my mobile app. I am just doing a test app for the time being so I have put a `TextView` so that one retrieved value from Thingspeak could be set in it.

I am getting the following errors and no value is appearing on the screen of my app. My device uses `API 17` and I know that `RippleDrawable` was added as from `API 21` but I have tried various solutions proposed for this kind of error(adding the latest Support Library which matches the SDK, changing `Vector` to Selector in `drawable`) but none of them worked so I cannot figure out the problem is in my codes or the fact my device uses `API 17`. Either way, please provide me with some fixes.

Logcat:

```
   12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onPointerCaptureChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPointerCaptureChanged
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15988: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onPointerCaptureChanged (Z)V
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15990: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15992: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15996: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 704: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    12-11 13:46:44.152 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
    12-11 13:46:44.152 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 726: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
    12-11 13:46:44.152 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 485: Landroid/content/Context;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getCodeCacheDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getCodeCacheDir
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 491: Landroid/content/Context;.getCodeCacheDir ()Ljava/io/File;
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColor, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 492: Landroid/content/Context;.getColor (I)I
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColorStateList
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 493: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getDataDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDataDir
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 495: Landroid/content/Context;.getDataDir ()Ljava/io/File;
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 496: Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getExternalCacheDirs, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getExternalCacheDirs
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 498: Landroid/content/Context;.getExternalCacheDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getExternalFilesDirs, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 500: Landroid/content/Context;.getExternalFilesDirs (Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/io/File;
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getNoBackupFilesDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 503: Landroid/content/Context;.getNoBackupFilesDir ()Ljava/io/File;
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getObbDirs, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getObbDirs
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 505: Landroid/content/Context;.getObbDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.202 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.isDeviceProtectedStorage, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.isDeviceProtectedStorage
    12-11 13:46:44.202 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 516: Landroid/content/Context;.isDeviceProtectedStorage ()Z
    12-11 13:46:44.202 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.202 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.startForegroundService, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startForegroundService
    12-11 13:46:44.202 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 531: Landroid/content/Context;.startForegroundService (Landroid/content/Intent;)Landroid/content/ComponentName;
    12-11 13:46:44.202 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.442 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.startActionModeForChild, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.startActionModeForChild
    12-11 13:46:44.442 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16457: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.startActionModeForChild (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
    12-11 13:46:44.442 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
    12-11 13:46:44.462 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
    12-11 13:46:44.462 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 493: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
    12-11 13:46:44.462 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.ImageButton.setImageIcon, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.setImageIcon
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16480: Landroid/widget/ImageButton;.setImageIcon (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)V
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 667: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 669: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    12-11 13:46:44.532 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
    12-11 13:46:44.532 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 193 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
    12-11 13:46:44.532 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16776: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize ()I
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeMinTextSize, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeMinTextSize
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16777: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeMinTextSize ()I
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16778: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeStepGranularity ()I
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16779: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes ()[I
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeTextType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeTextType
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16780: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeTextType ()I
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0008
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16823: Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration (IIII)V
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16824: Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes ([II)V
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16825: Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults (I)V
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.742 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes
    12-11 13:46:44.742 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16778: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeStepGranularity ()I
    12-11 13:46:44.742 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0197
    12-11 13:46:44.742 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.text.StaticLayout$Builder.obtain, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper.createStaticLayoutForMeasuring
    12-11 13:46:44.742 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 15266: Landroid/text/StaticLayout$Builder;.obtain (Ljava/lang/CharSequence;IILandroid/text/TextPaint;I)Landroid/text/StaticLayout$Builder;
    12-11 13:46:44.742 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0014
    12-11 13:46:44.742 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.isInLayout, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper.setRawTextSize
    12-11 13:46:44.742 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16815: Landroid/widget/TextView;.isInLayout ()Z
    12-11 13:46:44.742 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0021
    12-11 13:46:45.053 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_java.so
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.teerna.testapp.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/aTextView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 TextView tv;

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.aTextView);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new GetMethodDemo().execute("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/357670/feeds.json?results=2");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public class GetMethodDemo extends AsyncTask<String , Void ,String> {
    String server_response;



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(strings[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                server_response = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                Log.v("CatalogClient", server_response);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    // Converting InputStream to String
    private String readStream(InputStream in) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
          try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
        }   catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                }   catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return response.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);

        if (response != null) {
            String item=null;
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject jsonResponse = json.getJSONObject("Response");

                //Pulling items from array
                item = jsonResponse.getString("ID");

            } catch (JSONException j) {
                j.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.e("Response", "" + server_response);
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(item));
            }

       }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.teerna.testapp">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

just take `textView`  below `setContent()` like below

```
  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.aTextView);
    new GetMethodDemo().execute("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/357670/feeds.json?results=2");

}
```

Comment: check your import lines top of class file with **android.support.v7.app** or not

Comment: I have the following in my `dependencies`: `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'`
    `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'`

Comment: try with by removing compile **'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160924/discussion-between-omi-and-margo-roth-spiegelman).

Comment: Yes.I posted my imports of my java file in chat.